# Nest Noir Routes

Tags: clojure, routes, metaprogramming, noir

I have an app that generates keys based for specific datastores. If there are 7 such routes and 5 apps, there would be a total of 35 routes in my event.clj (or, if split out, 7/file in 5 files). I would like to do the following dynamically:

```
(defnested "/:app-name"
    (defpage "/generate/event" {:keys [app-name event-name time] :as key-map}
     (response/json
      {:key (key-model/build-key :event key-map)}))

    (defpage "/generate/event/unread" {:keys [app-name event-name] :as key-map}
     (response/json
      {:key (key-model/build-key :unread-for-event key-map)}))
)
```

That way I can write each route once and then pass around the app-name (instead of passing it in the query params, which works but isn't very RESTful.

BONUS

How can I dynamically call a namespace so that `key-model/build-key` becomes a call to `redis-model/build-key` or `riak-model/build-key` based on the app name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question but isn't this what your are looking for:

```
(defpage "/:app-name/generate/event" {:keys [app-name event-name time] :as key-map}
    (response/json
      {:key (key-model/build-key :event key-map)}))

(defpage "/:app-name/generate/event/unread" {:keys [app-name event-name] :as key-map}
     (response/json
      {:key (key-model/build-key :unread-for-event key-map)}))
```

BONUS

I will also go for a simple solution of having a map with the funcitons to generate the keys, something like:

```
(def key-gen {"redis" redis-model/build-key
       "riak" riak/build-key})

(response/json
      {:key ((get key-gen app-name) :event key-map)})
```

If you really want to dynamically find the build-key function, you can do something like:

```
(defn build-key [app-name] 
   (let [the-ns (symbol (str app-name "-model"))] 
      (require the-ns) 
      (ns-resolve the-ns 'build-key)))
```

Comment: yep I can do that for each of the routes, but I'm looking for a better solution for the method calling (so someone can add a backend without worrying about adding it to a hash-map in the routes) Though using `get` would allow for a default value to return a 404 or 422

Comment: updated answer. You can still return 404 or 422 if the `the-ns` or the return value is nil

Comment: This is just the kind of crazy I'm looking for ;)